# How do I make this CSS overlay without making this happen

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see in the image there is a problem and it basically knocks down the image I need it just floats over the top right corner of header.

#### HTML

```
<header id="header">
  <div id="lang">
    <a href="index.html">English</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: `position: absolute`?

Comment: Please tell us what is the problem and what you are trying to achieve. What do you want to do with the "English" link?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<header id="header">
  <div id="lang">
    <a href="index.html">English</a>
  </div>
</header>

<style>
#header{
   position: relative;
}

#lang{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: it worked! but now my link isn't clickable edit: fixed it with z-index. thanks a lot for your help. could you explain the reasoning behind why I had to make header relative.

Comment: this might not right, but as far as i know, in order to get your #land positioning absolutely top right corner of it's parent div, this parent div should be positioned relatively

Comment: Thank you for your generous help, I wish there was a way to donate to people on this website.

Comment: From the w3schools.com web site: "An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is <html>". So in other words, you have to set the header to relative in order for your absolutely positioned element to take that as its reference.